# Variational function versus variational solution

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I want to minimize the functional $F[f(x)]$ and I'm going to try this in two different ways:

1. First I am going to numerically minimize the functional $F[f(x)]$, leading to the "true solution" $f(x)$.
2. Second I am going to insert a variational function $\varphi_a(x)$ into the functional, where $a$ is a variational parameter which is found by minimizing the functional $F[f(x)]$.

What I now want to know is how well my variational function $\varphi_a(x)$ approaches my correct solution $f(x)$. I was wondering if there are any general ways to do this? The goal is to eventually set up an objective criterion to compare three different variational function and pick out the best one to approximate my problem.

My first guess was to compare the norm of the difference in order to get one number that I can compare. This means that I will be comparing the number (let me call it $C$):
$$
C=\sqrt{\int_D(f(x)-\varphi_a(x))^2}
$$
for the three different variational functions. If the variational function $\varphi_a(x)$ and the true solution $f(x)$ coincide, $C$ will equal zero, if not $C$ will become nonzero.

Now I was wondering if this was the best way to do this, or if there are better methods available ?

Comment: What do you mean by inserting a variational function $\varphi_a(x)$?

Comment: @felipeh So either I look for the function f(x) by minimizing the functional. Or either I propose a functional form $\varphi_a(x)$ that I fill into the functional, in this case I just have to minimize $F[\varphi_a(x)]$ with respect to $a$.

Comment: Without being more specific, it's hard to distinguish proposals 1 and 2, since "numerically minimizing" $F[f(x)]$ usually means choosing a set of parameters $a$ that determines $\varphi_a(x)$ and minimizing with respect to $a$.

Comment: @felipeh I'm not asking which way is the best, I'm asking what the best way is to compare the two results $f(x)$ and $\varphi_a(x)$. Is the ordinary least squares (as proposed above) the best way to compare both, or are there better methods to do this ?